# How to transfer weightings to tensorflow RNN cell

Tags: tensorflow

I have a set of weightings of the trained model implemented in matlab. I would like to port the weightings to tensorflow. However, tf.rnn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell with 500 cell has weight matrix with shape (1524, 2000). why 1524? why 2000? This does not fit the dimensions of my weightings at all.

My model has 3 hidden layers, each has 1000 nodes, and the last hidden layer is temporal layer(Recurrent). the input dimension is 1539. output dimension is 1026.
The temporal layer has 1x1000 temporal weighting and 1000x1000 layer weighting and 1x1000 for bias.

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 3, 1024], dtype=tf.float32, name='input')
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(500)
output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    var = [x for x in tf.trainable_variables() if x.name=='RNN/LSTMCell/W_0:0']
    val = sess.run(var)
    # why 1524x2000?
    print(val[0].shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are calling your cell using x as input. The size of the weight matrix will be (500 + 1024) x (4 * 500). The LSTM has four gating functions but for efficiency reasons their individual matrices are concatenated together. That's why the second dimension of the matrix is 4 * 500. The first dimension is the size of the cell plus the size of the input because it needs to be multiplied with the input concatenated with the output from the previous step.

Comment: So I can I use my pretrained weighting? The shape of weight matrix is different... Should I implement a new kind of cell on my own instead of continuing using built-in LSTMCell?

Comment: the matlab code does not use any toolbox for neural network. It seems that it does not use anything like LSTM

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there's BasicRNNCell available. But it also has a concated weighting matrix. I think I almost get it. Just need to take a look at the implementation of BasicRNNCell

Answer (score 0):

first convert your pre-trained weights into tensor, this can be done by reading a file containing your weights and using `weights = tf.convert_to_tensor(your_weights)`

then find your name of lstm cell weights(this can be done by list all ops in this graph)

finally use `tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_graph_def=your_meta_graph_def, input_map={"lstm-cell-weights-name": weights})`(the most important thing is the `input_map` argument)

**Only for version after 0.12.**

because older version doesn't support `input_map` argument